# onstart() on Fragment is getting called twice in android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an activity on which I have one fragment. In onStart() of fragment I have all network calls.When app comes from background onStart() is getting called twice and all network are called twice and I also observed that onCreate()is called only once.Has some one faced such issue.Please help me out.
My code for fragment transaction is as below

```
 MainFragment myFragment = new MainFragment ();
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, myFragment, "MyFragment");
                fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: I suspect that one of the calls of onStart() is from another instance of your fragment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try checking whether the fragment is already added before replacing

```
final FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
final Fragment content = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.content_frame);
if (content == null || !(content instanceof MainFragment)) {
    final FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    final MainFragment myFragment = new MainFragment();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, myFragment, "MyFragment");
    fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
}
```

Comment: No Luck still the same

Comment: @ARP ша all fragments of R.id.content_frame are instances of MainFragment it will fail. Is this the case? And please post your onCreate method.

Answer (score 0):

`commit` or `commitAllowingStateLoss` is an asynchronous excute, so `fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.content_frame);` will a `null` before first `commit` finished, that will cause `replace` called twice.
you can debug `onStart` function, and see the hashCode of current `Fragment` object.

I replace `commit` to `commitNow`:

```java
FragmentManager fragmentManager = activity.getFragmentManager();
        Fragment lifeFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(TAG_FRAGMENT);
        if (lifeFragment == null || !(lifeFragment instanceof LifeFragment)) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .add(new LifeFragment(), TAG_FRAGMENT)
                        .commitNowAllowingStateLoss();
            }else {
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .add(new LifeFragment(), TAG_FRAGMENT)
                        .commitAllowingStateLoss();
            }
        }
```