# Runnable runs twice for no obvious reason (inside DialogFragment)

Tags: android, runnable

The code looks like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    handler = new Handler();
    }
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    handler.post(runnable);
}

Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Timber.e("DEBUGGING Runnable");
    }
};
```

This only happens on some devices (Huawei P9 lite VNS-L21 and Galaxy J5 SM-J500FN), on others it doesn't happen at all.

Details:

1. The display does not timeout/fade during this process.
2. Runnable is not mentioned/executed in any other place.
3. Fragment onStart() is called only once

Could this all be a bug in old Android versions?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22405008/onstart-on-fragment-is-getting-called-twice-in-android

Comment: onStart() is only called **once**